# Doctrine2 Many to Many doesn't return array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

If I have the following class defined,

```
class Category {

    /**
     *
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     * @JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $tags;
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to get all the tags associated to this category by:

```
$categoryTags = $category->getTags();
```

The object in $categoryTags after the above assignment is of the type  Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection while I expect it to be an array.

I added the association values in category_tag table manually with sql commands, but I can see that they are valid.

My Tags class looks like this:

```
class Tag extends Tag{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=60,nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $tag;

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the collection to be an array? See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/architecture.html#architecture-persistent-fields

Comment: See also http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html?highlight=many-to-many#collections

Comment: `protected $tags;` shouuld be public, or make a method to return it like `public getTags(){ return $this->tags; }`

Comment: @manix I am using getters that's not the problem

Comment: @Phil I expect it to be an array of Tag objects because I've associated those tags with this Category. How do I get an array of tags if Category->tags is Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doctrine does not return simple arrays for associated entity collections. Rather, it returns implementations of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection`.

You can use these as you would an array as they extend the [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php), [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) and [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interfaces.

If you *really* need an array (and I can't think of a reason why), you can use the `toArray()` method.

Please read the documentation to understand why Doctrine does not use simple arrays

- http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html?highlight=many-to-many#collections
- http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/architecture.html#persistent-fields

Comment: Here is a reason: you have type hinting in PHP and you don't want to couple yourself with a DoctrineCollection inside your code. Any thought on that?

Comment: @danip So type-hint to `ArrayAccess` instead or don't use Doctrine

Comment: I don't think there is a better alternative then Doctrine at this point and ArrayAccess doesn't imply you can use count on it. It's a shame PHP is to blame for this necessary coupling to a framework(array type is not good enough it seems).

Comment: @danip or you know, you could just be pragmatic. `Collection` is reasonably nebulous and it's not part of the ORM